# Why drawing on memory bitmap doesn't work as expected?

Tags: c++, gdi+

I'm trying to draw on memory bitmap and have weird results. This is a code I have:

```
HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(hWnd);
HDC hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
HBITMAP hMemoryBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, w, h);

HBITMAP hBitmapOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMemory, hMemoryBitmap);

Graphics *memoryGraphics = Graphics::FromHDC(hdcMemory);
SolidBrush brush(Color(255, 255, 0, 0));
memoryGraphics->FillRectangle(&brush, 0, 0, w, h);

POINT dcOffset = { 0, 0 };
SIZE size = { w, h };
BLENDFUNCTION bf;
bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
bf.BlendFlags = 0;
bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
bf.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

UpdateLayeredWindow(hWnd, hdcScreen, &dcOffset, &size, hdcMemory, &dcOffset, 0, &bf, ULW_ALPHA);

delete memoryGraphics;
ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcScreen);
SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmapOld);
DeleteDC(hdcMemory);
DeleteObject(hMemoryBitmap);
```

And it gives me semitransparent! Why? I clearly specified `Color(255, 255, 0, 0)` in brush?

Comment: Can you try calling `memoryGraphics->Flush()` before `UpdateLayeredWindow()`. Or even better, moving `delete memoryGraphics` to just before `UpdateLayeredWindow()`.

Comment: @rodrigo Yep, tried. The result is the same. But I found this in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534427(v=vs.85).aspx): "All four component values range from 0 to 255. An alpha component value of 0 specifies that the color is transparent, and an alpha value of 255 specifies that the color is opaque. **Alpha component values from 1 through 254 specify the degree to which the color is blended with the background when the color is rendered.**" I can't fully understand, but maybe this is the case. I set alpha to 254 and that fixed a problem.

Comment: That 254 thing is weird! It may be related to [this doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183393(v=vs.85).aspx): _When the AlphaFormat member is AC_SRC_ALPHA, the source bitmap must be 32 bpp._ Maybe your bitmap is a 24 bpp? And it mutates to a 32 bpp when using partially transparent colors (a!=255)? You could try replacing the `CreateCompatibleBitmap()` with a more specific one.

Comment: Hmm. I changed line `HBITMAP hMemoryBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, w, h);` to  `Bitmap memoryBitmap(w, h, PixelFormat32bppARGB);
 HBITMAP hMemoryBitmap;
 memoryBitmap.GetHBITMAP(0, &hMemoryBitmap);` and all works. Thanks!